# convert type int to my custom enum

Tags: c#, .net

My model has property

```
public enum CheckStatus
{
   A = 1,
   B = 2,
   C = 3,
}
public CheckStatus Status { get; set; }
```

and inside razor view I want to switch this property like

```
@switch (Model.Status)
{
    case 1:
    default:
       <div>Selected A</div>
       break;
    case 2:
       <div>Selected B</div>
       break;
    case 3:
       <div>Selected C</div>
       break;
}
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'CheckStatus'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You ought to do like `case A:`

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @decPL my question is: how many eggs do I need to bake perfect omlet ? I think it's obvious from error I provide.

Comment: @user1765862 and why don't you have the enum values for your switch cases? You don't need/care about the int value for this.

Comment: @user1765862 The answer is obvious too, and included in the error message itself. Do an explicit cast ie `(int)Model.Status`. But why don't you use the Enum values?

Comment: @user1765862 as mentioned above, the answer is obvious as well. Oh, and your question about the eggs is unfortunately an indicator that you don't know how to ask unambiguous technical questions (hint: it depends on several things you didn't care to disclose).

Comment: @decPL you're right about eggs :) But I remain that my question was obvious.

Comment: @user1765862 We'll have to agree to disagree then, especially since the answer to your 'obvious question' was essentially contained in the error message.

Comment: @decPL no worriez, it's a sunny day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Your `switch` statement parameter and the case `Label` must be of the same datatype.*

so cast your enum to `int` like this

```
switch ((int)Model.Status)
{
    case 2:
       <div>Selected B</div>
       break;
    case 3:
       <div>Selected C</div>
       break;
    default:
       <div>Selected A</div>
       break;
}
```

or use the `CheckStatus` in your case statement as well

```
switch (Model.Status)
{

    case CheckStatus.B:
       <div>Selected B</div>
       break;
    case CheckStatus.C:
       <div>Selected C</div>
       break;
    default:
       <div>Selected A</div>
       break;
}
```

I removed the first case as you are not doing anything in that case. Also put the `default` case at the end which make things readable. You can also use the `Case 1` and remove the `default` (if you want)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
switch((int) Model.Status) { }
```

to reach your goal!

Appendix: `Model.Status` would just return A, B etc, not the integer values behind.